# Please Help me in creating regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

please tell me what will be the regex for replacing values "_$$12" from a string where "12" can be any digit.
i have tried with various combination but '$' is creating issue.

Comment: actually remove it :)    (the integer value can be changed so needed regex)

Answer (score 3):

Since `$` has special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape it:

```
@"_\$\$\d\d"
```

Comment: @RajeshRolen-DotNetDeveloper - Sure. `\d\d` means two digits, as in your example, but if that's not the correct pattern (where it can be one or more, the `\d+` would be more suitable.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `Regex.Escape("blah");` to escape a regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

`$` is has special meaning in regexes, it marks the end of the string. E.g.

```
Regex.Replace(input_string,@"_\$\$\(d+)", @"\1");
```

Will replace `_$$12` with just `12`.

Comment: Since you demonstrate this in C# you probably want to escape your `\ ` chars, or use a verbatim string `@"_\$\$\(d+)"`.

Comment: @Omega, it's just an example. OP does not specified what a replacement should be. Maybe you can tell better?

Answer (score 1):

```
var sanitized = Regex.Replace("_$$12", @"_\$\$[0-9]+", "ReplacementString");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class RegExSample 
{
  static void Main() 
  {
    string text = "text _$$12 text";
    string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"_\$\$\d+", "#replacement#");
    System.Console.WriteLine("result = [" + result + "]");
  }
}
```

See this code in action [here](http://ideone.com/W4WN6).

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
        string input = "_$$12";
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"_\$\$", string.Empty);
```

the output will be 12. and if you increase the input something like "_$$123456" then the output will be 123456